# Assets behaviour in multiplatform libGDX application

Tags: java, android, ios, mobile, libgdx

What is the best practice to store resources in libGDX library. I'm know that I can use `AssetManager` and also e.g. I can link the resources from android folder into iOS, but I dont know how it will behaviour on multiplatform devices. The resources are scale according to screen size/operating system, or I need to manually set diffrent size or resulution in each platform resource folder.I want to avoid any ovelaying or stretch behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about this and there is no "best" solution. However if you do already build for android just use the android assets folder. This is the default and will be used for other builds (due to the default libgdx project configurations).

The resources only scale if you tell them too. You can choose to use a viewport (a fit/fill viewport will not stretch but can add black/background bars that do not have the default aspect ratio). But you can also choose to implement screen dependency yourself by using the aspect ratio and the scale.

For instance:

A 1080x1920 mobile phone vs a 1440x1920 tablet
If you use a fit viewport you will have unused space on the tablet. if you use a fillviewport you might lose stuff on the phone. But if you take the phone as a default aspect ratio and calculate the width offset for the tablet (1440-1080/2) you can use this value to choose to put actors/sprites on the same location as on the prone (by using this offset) or relative to the screen edge (by using the screen size). I personally use this to place the UI relative to the screen and the game itself the same as on the phone. You can even choose to use a different layout depending on the aspect ratio.

Do note that in this way you will also have to calculate a global scale and use this everywhere in your application. This can be tedious to implement but gives you much more control!

So if you have a simple game and you don't care about tablets or different screen sizes I suggest you start with a fit viewport.

p.s. Not sure what you mean by "multiplatform devices", but as I said, the default libGDX setup does the heavy lifting here, so I suggest you use it!

Comment: In pure android development I can use the container/ text/ImageViews with specyfic size measure in dp/sp that looks the same on diffrent screen size devices. I also have 5 diffrent folders with  drawable assets with diffrent resolution. But in iOS the resolution of the assets are diffrent and I want to know if I need handle it or I can use the android assets

Comment: LibGDX is nothing like "pure android development". If you want to use DPI dependent assets you have to manage that yourself. Which is very possible. I personally do use resolution based assets (I have assets for low and high res, and choose which to load at startup).

All in app assets can be used on all platforms, the only platform dependent assets you need are iOS launch screens and icons for iOS and android.

Comment: Okey so the good way is to made a assets in couple resolution and programically decided which one are loaded

Comment: yes you can, or you can just scale them down. It does depend on how heavy your app is, but i would start off with a single high resolution (for instance target 1080x1920) and see how performance is when you run it with that on a low end device. Then decide if you need to implement lower resolution assets